# Send Email with attachment file (more than 10 MB) using GMAIL API in Javascript

Tags: javascript, gmail, gmail-api

How to Send Email with an attachment PDF file (more than 10 MB) using GMAIL API in Javascript. I tried with some code of PDF File attachment and send email as below.

```
const base64Data = 'Base64 PDF File string here (10 MB)'
const mixedB = 'mixedB';
const relatedB = 'relatedB';
const alternativeB = 'alternativeB';
const To = 'test@gmail.com'
const message = '<p>This is TEST EMAIL with PDF Attachment</p>'
const messageParts = [
  'From: ' + 'vijay@test.com',
  'To: ' + To,
  `Subject: This is Test Email`,
  'MIME-Version: 1.0',
  'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="' + mixedB + '"',
  '',
  '--' + mixedB,
  'Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="' + relatedB + '"',
  '',
  '--' + relatedB,
  'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="' + alternativeB + '"',
  '',
  '--' + alternativeB,
  'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8',
  '',
  message, // html content.
  '',
  '--' + alternativeB + '--',
  '',
  '--' + relatedB + '--',
  '',
  '--' + mixedB,
  'Content-Type: application/pdf;name="attachedFile.pdf"',
  'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64',
  'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="attachedFile.pdf"',
  '',
  base64Data, // base64 data of the file.
  '',
  '--' + mixedB + '--'
]

let aaa = messageParts.join('\r\n')

var sendRequest = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
  'userId': 'me',
  'uploadType': 'multipart',
  'resource': {
    'raw': window.btoa(aaa).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=+$/, '')
  }
});

return sendRequest.execute();
```

I am receiving an email, but the attached PDF File does not open after downloading. [image: See image]
Is there any silly mistake in the code? Please guide.

Comment: Does the code work with a different, smaller base64 string? Are you positive the base64 string is correct, and not a single byte is missing or bad?

Comment: Yes, working for a smaller file ( PDF and PNG both)

Comment: https://base64.guru/converter/encode/pdf, I am using this site for Base64 conversion from PDF

Answer (score 0):

You should do a [Resumable Upload](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads#resumable) instead of the multipart one.

As mentioned on the [Upload options](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads#uploads), the resumable upload is the better fit for larger files:

> Resumable upload: uploadType=resumable. For reliable transfer, especially important with larger files.